# How to know whether two datetimes cover exactly one day (DST issues)

Tags: python, datetime, dst, days

I have a piece of code that provided two timezone-aware Python `datetime`(s) tries to figure out if they are **exactly** the beginning and the end of the same day.

For most of the cases, checking that the difference (the `timedelta`) between the two dates is `23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds and 999999 microseconds`, works fine:

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta, date
import pytz
ny = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')

day=date(2019, 3, 11)

start_naive=datetime.combine(day, time.min)
start=ny.localize(start_naive)

end_naive=datetime.combine(day, time.max)
end=ny.localize(end_naive)

same_day_check = timedelta(hours=time.max.hour, 
                           minutes=time.max.minute, 
                           seconds=time.max.second, 
                           microseconds=time.max.microsecond)

print(f"Same day?")
(end - start) == same_day_check # This outputs True
```

⚠️ **However...**

On daylight savings time dates, a day doesn't last 23 hours, 59 min. 59 sec. and 999999 microseconds but +1 hour or -1 hour (in those dates, "a day" can last 22 hours, 59 min.. or 24 hour, 59 min...):

```
# ...

day=date(2019, 3, 10)  # DST start in NY timezone

# ...

same_day_check = timedelta(hours=time.max.hour, 
                           minutes=time.max.minute, 
                           seconds=time.max.second, 
                           microseconds=time.max.microsecond)

print(f"Same day?")
(end - start) == same_day_check # Now this is `False`
print(end-start) # This outputs 22:59:59.999999
```

Is there a more reliable way than this? Using `timedelta` like described above is clearly not a reliable solution.

Comment: To know if two datetime are in the same day, I would just compare their conversion to date. To know whether it the the beginning of days, I would control that hour, minute, second and microsecond are all null, and same logic for end of day.

Comment: I executed your example and I'm getting `True` and `23:59:59.999999` for the second part. It may be related to Python version - in 3.6 [`fold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fold) attribute has been added.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, that's a great idea and what I ended up doing. If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as chosen :) 

@Tupteq, thank you for the mention to `fold`. I didn't know it existed!. Fortunately (at least for now) those times are not expected to be in one of the repeated times/switching times (so far!!) but I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: @BorrajaX: Thank you, but I am too tired to write an answer by now... Feel free to write it yourself so that you can accept it.